# Ambiguous clause on mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to join 2 tables to get the matching values but am getting the ambiguous clause,

my code is here

```
SELECT *
FROM auction_media
  JOIN auctions
    ON auction_id = auction_id
    WHERE media_type = '3'
```

an example of my table structure can be found here
the error is Column 'auction_id' in on clause is ambiguous

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13583

what should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM auction_media
JOIN auctions
ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id
WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM auction_media
  JOIN auctions
    ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id
    WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias your tables. The problem is caused because multiple columns have the same name, in this case the ones you are trying to join. Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM auction_media AS am
    JOIN auctions AS a
    ON am.auction_id = a.auction_id
    WHERE media_type = '3'
```

UPDATE: I aliased them to make it shorter and more readabile, but another option is to use the full table.column name, such as auction_media.auction_id

Or you can use 'USING' instead

```
SELECT * 
FROM auction_media
    JOIN auctions
    USING (auction_id)
    WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `am.auction_id` in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM auction_media
  JOIN auctions
    ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id
    WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refer the column name based on table name.

```
SELECT * FROM auction_media am JOIN auction a ON am.auction_id = a.auction_id
WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
SELECT * FROM auction_media JOIN auctions ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id WHERE media_type = '3'
```

Read [SQL JOIN](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm)